# Why is it called the ‘sound-image’ in Saussurean structural linguistics?

Tags: structural-linguistics

The term “sound-image” seems to suggest a mental image that the signifier evokes, but then the explanations from all sources seem to say that it doesn’t involve image, only words and sounds. Why is it called “sound-image” then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are often confused over "sound" which can be considered from at least two perspectives: physical patterns of vibrations of air particles, and a human cognitive representation of the sound wave. Saussure calls this representation the "acoustic image" (*image acoustique*) or in the standard English translation "sound-image". This is a variety of the Cartesian representationalist idea of mental images or projections. "Image" here really means "representation", the problem is that the theory of mental representations was not very well developed until after (and thanks to) Saussure.